# TitlePageIndicator CirclePageIndicator both on same ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I'm developing an Android 3.1 tablet application.

I'm using a ViewPager with Fragments and also I'm using [ViewPageIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) to show a TitlePageIndicator and a CirclePageIndicator.

My problem is that I can use both together.

```
public class FillEReportFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private FillEReportFragmentPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.fill_ereport_paged);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new FillEReportFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

        CirclePageIndicator mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);
        //mIndicator.setSnap(true);
        //mIndicator.setCurrentItem(0);

        //Bind the title indicator to the adapter
        TitlePageIndicator titleIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.titles);
        titleIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);
    }
}
```

It only works the last one which is bound to `mViewPager`.

**How can I bind TitleIndicator and CirclePageIndicator with the same ViewPager?**

Comment: I gave an answer for the same question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326631/i-am-trying-to-implement-a-titlepageindicator-and-a-circlepageindicator-on-the-s/21328277#21328277